# Python super() chain not advancing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

Python newbie here, would appreciate some help with multiple inheritance!

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
class Base1:
    def display(self):
        print('Base1')

class Base2:
    def display(self):
        print('Base2')

class Derived1 (Base1):
    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print('Derived1')

class Derived2 (Base2):
    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print('Derived2')

class Derived (Derived1, Derived2):
    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print('Derived')

Derived().display()
```

I was expecting that the output of this would print the names of all the classes involved in the hierarchy, but it's not so. Further, if I add `super().display()` to both `Base1` and `Base2`, I get the error `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'display'`.

What's wrong?

Comment: What do you expect this to do? What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes `Base1` and `Base2` implicitly inherit from `object` which has no `display` method. This explains the `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'display'` exception.

The output of this code should be:

```
Base1
Derived1
Derived
```

When inheriting from multiple classes, they are searched from left to right for attributes when `super` is called. Thus, `display` is found on `Derived1`, so `Derived2` is not looked at during the method resolution. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean an inheritance loop has to be "closed" in order for `super()` to call methods from all classes? In this case, does that mean I add `display()` to `object`?

Comment: Uhh, adding methods to `object` is probably not recommended. It might be better for you to create your own objects from scratch, with the base object having a `display` method. It's hard to say without real code examples. Keep in mind that a lot of things inherit from `object` (i.e. all non-primatives), so you don't really want to monkey-patch it as it is likely to cause unforeseen consequences.

Comment: One important takeaway for me was that `super()` must not be present in root class.